# Keyboard shortcut overlay

Tags: feature-request, editor, keyboard

I've just been trying to find a list of WMD editor keyboard shortcuts - and I can't see one. There's the formatting reference, but I can't see a keyboard shortcut list. Obviously this *could* be addressed as a FAQ entry, but there's a better way.

Google Reader has a very nice feature whereby if you hit "?" while you're not editing anything else, an overlay pops up with all the keyboard shortcuts. Obviously we couldn't use "?" in quite the same way, but even just a little "keyboard" button next to the help button at the top right of the edit box would be a reasonable trigger.

This would be particularly useful for any shortcuts which *don't* map directly to buttons. There may not be many (or even any) now, but I can imagine some possibilities, particularly if other feature requests are accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also, there is now an [official keyboard add-in for all Stack Exchange sites](https://stackapps.com/questions/2567/official-keyboard-shortcuts).

As documented [on the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/08/stack-exchange-keyboard-shortcuts/).

[image]
<sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stack-exchange-keyboard-shortcuts.png))</sub>

Comment: Whoa...."Can access your data on **all** websites"?(emphasis mine) Not that I don't trust SO, but is that necessary?

Answer (score 3):

Having the shortcuts in the tooltip mouseover for the editor toolbar buttons (as they currently are) isn't sufficient?

[image: mouseover editor tooltips]

Comment: I found those a while back and use them gratuitously. However, they've really screwed me up outside of SO. MS Office uses Ctrl+K for the hyperlink. I keep writing code in email, trying to Ctrl+K it and getting a URL prompt.

Comment: Hacktually, I didn't notice that before.